# Paho MQTT module not returning full message from subscribed topic

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, paho

i'm currently working with a sensor that sends bytes through MQTT and i'm using Paho MQTT module to make a testing environment so i can learn the back-end process of it.
Here is my code just to continuously print the messages that the topic sends.

```
def on_message(sensorclt, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload)

def on_connect(sensorclt, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print('Connected')
        sensorclt.subscribe([(Topics[0], 0), (Topics[1], 0), (Topics[2], 0)])
    else:
        print("Failed to connect")
sensorclt = mqtt.Client()
sensorclt.connect(host='iot.eclipse.org', port=1883)
sensorclt.on_connect = on_connect
sensorclt.on_message = on_message
sensorclt.loop_forever()
```

Here is the output of a few seconds working:

```
b'\x01\x01\x00\x1f\xa4\x94Z\xe3\x03\x00'
b'\x01\x01\x01\x1f\xa4\x94Z\n\x00\x80'
b'\x01\x01\x02\x1f\xa4\x94Z\x06\x00\x00'
b'\x01\x01\x00 \xa4\x94Z\xe4\x03\x00'
b'\x01\x01\x01 \xa4\x94Z\n\x00\x80'
b'\x01\x01\x02 \xa4\x94Z\x06\x00\x00'
b'\x01\x01\x00!\xa4\x94Z\xe3\x03\x00'
b'\x01\x01\x01!\xa4\x94Z\t\x00\x80'
```

The thing is that the sensor manufacturer tutorial says that there should be 10 bytes, not 8 or even sometimes 7 as the output is pointing. I can prove that information using a simple node-red environment to show that the topic is really sending 10 bytes and never less then that and node-red always receives 10, and again, nothing less .

[image: Node-red Debug node with "Complete Message Object" as Output]

Why is this happening? How can i counter it?

Comment: Removing the Node-RED tag as this really is more about the python code

Comment: Ok, thank you, just placed it there cause i mentioned it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the examples you have shown have exactly 10 bytes:

```
'\x01' '\x01' '\x00' '\x1f' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\xe3' '\x03' '\x00'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x01' '\x1f' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\n' '\x00' '\x80'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x02' '\x1f' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\x06' '\x00' '\x00'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x00' ' ' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\xe4' '\x03' '\x00'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x01' ' ' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\n' '\x00' '\x80'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x02' ' ' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\x06' '\x00' '\x00'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x00' '!' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\xe3' '\x03' \x00'
'\x01' '\x01' '\x01' '!' '\xa4' '\x94' 'Z' '\t' '\x00' '\x80'
```

It just happens that some of those bytes fall with in the normal character range e.g. !, Z, space, new line (\n) or tab (\t)

Comment: So how i'm supposed to access them separately ? And why on python it's showing those espacial characters and on node-red it doesn't happen? I don't understand much about bytes

Comment: It's just how python does string representation of byte arrays.  You need to look at how to access individual elements in python arrays, something like `msg.payload[5]` would access the 6th element in the array (indexes start at 0)